# Rendimiento de Sitio Web

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

alguien me puede dar su opinion sobre el rendimiento de mi sitio web: https://chorotega.hn/ , agradeceria que me dieran las oportunidades de mejora,

de verdad muchas gracias.

Saludos Cordiales

Comment: Tu pregunta, en su formato actual, está basada en opiniones y es muy, muy amplia. Tampoco sabemos cuál es el stack de tecnologías, si usas una BD, cómo la usas, en qué servidor está desplegado, para cuántos usuarios concurrentes lo montaste, etc etc etc. ¿Has identificado algún posible problema?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], tienes la reputación suficiente para preguntar esto en el [chat], recomiendo eliminar esto y mejor cuestionar allá, ya que al momento llevas 3 de 5 votos para que la pregunta quede cerrada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando abres tu pagina en Google chrom clic CTRL+SHIFT+I esto abre herramientas de developer busca el tab Lighthouse y desde alli puedes verificar el rendimiento de tu pagina.
Cuando lo hecho esto es lo que ha ocurrido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]